# Pass bean:write value from Jsp to Action Class

Tags: java, html, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts-1

I'm new to struts and I just can't get my head around this one.

**candyViewJobs.jsp** page has an array list displayed in a table like below

```
<form method="post" name="form">
                <table id='tableViewJobs'> 
                    <tr>
                        <th width="14%">Job Code</th>
                        <th width="14%">Job Name</th>
                        <th width="14%">Qualification Required</th>
                        <th width="16%">Skills</th>
                        <th width="14%">Experience Required</th>
                        <th width="14%">Vacancies</th>
                    </tr>
                    <logic:iterate name="view" id="jobs">
                    <tr>
                        <td><bean:write name="jobs" property="jcode"/></td>
                        <td><bean:write name="jobs" property="jname"/></td>
                        <td><bean:write name="jobs" property="qualify"/></td>
                        <td><bean:write name="jobs" property="skills"/></td>
                        <td><bean:write name="jobs" property="xp"/></td>
                        <td><bean:write name="jobs" property="vac"/></td>
                        <td><input type="button" value="Apply"/></td>
                        <td><input type="button" value="View More Details" onclick="location.href='viewDetails.do'"/></td>
                    </tr>                          
                    </logic:iterate>
                </table>      
            </form>
```

I need to call my action class and access the jcode which is unique to every mentioned job. How do i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<h:param value="jCode">` to pass the jCode.